# Merge distinct arrays into one array in query result

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm newbie to PHP and CodeIgniter. So I have a **database query result** like this:

```
Result = array(

A = array(
        [a]=>'1',
        [b] =>'2',
     );

B = array(
        [a] =>'1',
        [b] =>'3',
     );

C = array(
        [a] =>'1',
        [b] =>'4',
     );

**and more...**

);
```

So how can I merge them into one array like this:

```
Result = array(

     Z = array(

        [a] =>'1',
        [b] => array(

               [0] =>'2',
               [1] =>'3',
               [2] =>'4',
        );

     );
```

Thanks you so much...

Comment: you want to combine them all into a single array, with non-duplicate values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$A = array( 'a' => '1', 'b' => '2', 'c' => '3');
$B = array( 'a' => '1', 'b' => '3', 'd' => '4');
$C = array( 'a' => '1', 'b' => '4', 'c' => '5');

$Result = array($A, $B, $C);
$Z = array();
foreach ($Result as $set) {
    foreach ($set as $key => $val) {
        if (isset($Z[$key])) {
            if (is_array($Z[$key])) {
                $Z[$key][] = $val;
            } elseif ($Z[$key] != $val) {
                $Z[$key] = array($Z[$key], $val);
            }
        } else {
            $Z[$key] = $val;
        }
    }
}

print_r($Z);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [a] => 1
    [b] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 4
        )

    [c] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 5
        )

    [d] => 4
)
```

If you want unique values per key, for instance if you want to avoid `a` equalling `array(1, 1, 2)`, then you can do this:

```
$Z = array();
foreach ($Result as $set) {
    foreach ($set as $key => $val) {
        if (!isset($Z[$key])) {
            $Z[$key] = array();
        }
        $Z[$key][] = $val;
    }
}

foreach($Z as $k => $v) {
    $newv = array_unique($v);
    if (count($newv) == 1) {
        $Z[$k] = $newv[0];
    } else {
        $Z[$k] = $newv;
    }
}

print_r($Z);
```

Comment: Sorry but maybe **more generic** is quite a thing I looking for. This is a database query result so I can't set input arrays by myself... Thank you so much...

Comment: @AzrielOmega This couldn't be much more generic. The solution takes an array of arrays and merges them as per your specification. Just replace array($A, $B, $C) in the foreach on line 7 with your query result.

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it's equally great; I just chose to avoid **if/else** in mine :)

Comment: I appreciate it, but our answers produce completely different results.

Comment: Sorry, sberry. I messed up with my code really hard and have a mistake when edit your code. Your code now work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I would have gone for this myself:

```
    $result = array_merge_recursive($a, $b, $c);
    foreach($result as $k => $v) $result[$k] = array_unique($v);
    print_r($result);
```

Comment: Now, that's a good answer.  This should be the accepted answer.  PHP and all of it's crazy built-ins... I can never keep track of them all.

Comment: @sberry I love how there's always 15 ways to skin the cat :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 
$final_array = array();
foreach ($Result as $key=>$value){
  foreach ($value as $inner_key=>$inner_value){
     $final_array[] = $inner_value; //this adds all the values into a single array 
  }
}

$final_array = array_unique($final_array); // this removes all duplicates
```

### Edit

```
 
$final_array = array();
foreach ($Result as $key=>$value){
  foreach ($value as $inner_key=>$inner_value){
     $final_array[$inner_key] = $inner_value; //this adds all the values into a single array; duplicate keys will simply replace one another during the iteration 
  }
}

//$final_array = array_unique($final_array); // this part is no longer required
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not certain, but I don't think this is what the OP is looking to do.

Comment: Why not? The first part turns it into a single array; the second part removes all the duplicated values; that's faster than creating a bunch of **if** statements.

Comment: The output from the your solution is a flat array of unique values.  I think the OP wants them grouped by their original keys.

Comment: Reviewing the Result again, all I see is a flat array wrapped inside another array, not multiple arrays unlike before; but if that's the case, I can simply edit the answer reflect that.

Comment: `Z` is not a flat array, it has a single element for `a`, but `b` is another nested array.

Comment: Thanks you Kneel-Before-ZOD and sberry. Now I can get the array that I needed. But the original keys is missing so please 'edit the answer reflect that'. Thank all of you so much...

Comment: @AzrielOmega: How do you mean the `original keys is missing`?  What keys are you trying to preserve that are not present in my answer?

Comment: @AzrielOmega: did you even look at what this answer outputs?  Didn't you want to preserve all values for `b`, not just the last one?

Comment: @AzrielOmega: That doesn't tell me a whole lot.  Is the output of my answer the output you were looking for?

Comment: I asked him what he basically wanted before responding to it; all duplicate values are combined as one; if that's the goal, my answer accomplished it; if not, it didn't.

Comment: @AzrielOmega: Can you edit the question to reflect your intent.  I don't mean to sound like an ass or anything, but the example you showed for what output you were expecting is exactly what mine outputs.  If for no other reason, update the question to clear up my vast confusion.

Comment: Ah yes. I tested your function and your output is exactly what I mean. But the problem is by myself. I don't know how and where to input my query result to receive the output. I will try to figure it out right after my finish my appointment and answer later. Thank you so much.